# Filter in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, filter

I have a problem with filter function in dplyr.

```r
tablita <- tabla %>% 
  filter(control_1 > 0 & control_2 > 0 &
         treated_1 > 0 & treated_2 > 0)
```

Why this filter filters a rows with this values.

```
control_1 = 0
control_2 = 0
treated_1 = 1
treated_2 = 0
```

Am I not supposed to say that all 4 have to be greater than 0 for it to filter?

Comment: Please check the `str(tabla)` to check whether the class of those columns are numeric/integer  or show a small reproducible example wiwth `dput(head(tabla))`

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the OR condition, `|` instead of `&`?

Comment: By "filters a row with this values", do you mean that it is allowing that row to remain and should not, or that it is not returning that row and should?

Comment: that row should stay but it is filtering it

Comment: Because `> 0` removes rows with zeros.

Comment: Okay, but putting the symbol & does not mean that you have to meet all 4 conditions at the same time?

Comment: It does. What you are saying with your `filter(..)` call is that all four must be true at the same time for the row to remain. Since you have three columns where the value is not `> 0`, the row is removed; one such column would suffice for the row to be removed. If you want to keep a row if _any_ of the rows are `> 0`, then replace your `&` with `|`. While there may be more efficient ways to do it, I think they're outside the scope of a comment.